# How to send '#' to chat with Telegram bot API?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, telegram-api

I'm trying to send a text for example "Hello # World" with Telegram API with this url:

```
https://api.telegram.org/bot'token'/sendMessage?chat_id='chatid'&text=Hello+#+World
```

But I just receive `Hello`

I also tried to encode it like this:

```
https://api.telegram.org/bot'token'/sendMessage?chat_id='chatid'&text=Hello+%23+World
```

But I just receive `Hello %23 World`.

Any solution to receive `Hello # World`? Thanks :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not [url-encode](https://www.urlencoder.org/) the string properly, it should be

```
Hello%20%23%20World
```

Instead off

```
Hello+%23+World
```

---

The complete url:

```
https://api.telegram.org/bot<TOKEN>/sendMessage?chat_id=<CHAT-ID>&text=Hello%20%23%20World
```

---

[image]